# I can't parse date from sqlite. ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime, simpledateformat

When I take datatime value from database then I get "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 2008-06-29 20:45:00"

**My code:**

```
try {
    Cursor cur = db.query("table", new String[] { "_id", "id_m", "date_time"}, "id_m=31", null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    cur.moveToFirst();
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS").parse(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("date_time")));
        long unixTimestamp = date.getTime() / 1000;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Can anybody explain me why?**

Comment: Look at your format. Now at your date. Back to the format... and to the date. That's the date your date could be if your date had milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time in your database uses the 24-hour clock, but you have specified `hh` for your hours field which limits the value to 1 through 12. Your pattern should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

Comment: @Dave Newton, you was right. The problem was in format.
Right format: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" - without SSS
It is strange, that earlier it works with date inserted by hand. But after loading date from server into the database this error appear.